# Como recorrer data en JQuery de un pedido AJAX

Tags: jquery

Tengo un archivo claseTorneo y el metodo de insertar uno nuevo, luego de insertar hace una consulta del id.
Dicho id quiero devolverlo para crear la vista de grupos de jugadores de dicho torneo, trabajo con MVC.

```
 public function registrarTorneo($nombreTorneo,$Fecha,$Localidad,$iddisciplina){
   try

{
                $sqltorneo="INSERT INTO torneo(idtorneo,nombretorneo,Fecha,Localidad,Iddisciplina) VALUES (null,'".$nombreTorneo."','".$Fecha."','".$Localidad."',".$iddisciplina.");";
                $sqlidtorneo='select max(idtorneo) as id from torneo order by idtorneo desc;';
             
                $conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion();
                $conexion->beginTransaction();
                $conexion->query($sqltorneo);
                $conexion->commit();
                $stm=$conexion->prepare($sqlidtorneo);
          
                $stm->execute();
                $array=$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


                 return $array;
         

}catch(Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
    
}
}
```

entonces tengo el procesoTorneo donde creo un objeto de dicho tipo:

```
 if (isset($_POST['opcion'])=='crear'){
    $c=new Torneo();
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
    $localidad=$_POST['localidad'];
    $dis=$_POST['dis'];
    $grupos=$_POST['grupos'];
    $jpg=$_POST['jxg'];
    $id=$c->registrarTorneo($nombre,$fecha,$localidad,$dis);

 echo json_encode($id);
}
```

Y cuando intento obtener el id hago : `data[0].id`

Si hago: `console.log(data)` obtengo:  ***[{"id":"56"}]***

```
$("#nuevotorneo").on("click",function(){
if (validaForm()==true){

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
data:{'opcion':'crear','nombre':$("#nombre").val(),'fecha':$("#fechahora").val(),'localidad':$('select[id="localidad"] option:selected').text(),
'dis':$("#disciplina").val(),'grupos':$("#numGrupos").val(),'jxg':$("#numjp").val()},
        url: '/billar/views/modules/torneo/procesoTorneo.php', 
        
        beforeSend: function(){
            /*
            * Esta función se ejecuta durante el envió de la petición al
            * servidor.
            * */
  
      
            },
        complete:function(){
          
          
        },          
        success: function(data){
            /*
            * Se ejecuta cuando termina la petición y esta ha sido
            * correcta
            * */
            console.log(data);

       //   window.location.href="index.php?controller=torneo&action=fasegrupos";
        },
        error: function(){
            /*
            * Se ejecuta si la peticón ha sido erronea
            * */
            alert("Problemas al tratar de enviar el formulario");
        }
    });
    // Nos permite cancelar el envio del formulario
    return false;}    });
```

Entonces cual es la manera adecuada de acceder al valor de id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que al no indicar `dataType` en tu petición Ajax, te lo devuelve con el `dataType` por defecto que es `html` y para leerlo como JSON tendrías que hacer un `JSON.parse` en Ajax.

Dado que usas MVC deberías tener un tipo de salida JSON en la Vista, al que le mandarías las salidas JSON, sea de los datos, sea de los errores.

Una solución más simple es indicar el `dataType` y asegurar del lado del servidor siempre una respuesta JSON.

Para eso deberás modificar un poco el manejo de errores también, evitando resolver con un simple `die`, y enviando algo como: `$outPut=array ("error"=>"mensaje de error");`.

Sin meternos con el lío de la vista, lo haremos a mano, porque así lo tienes, pero considera simplificar haciendo uso de la vista (como bien sabes la `V` de `MVC` significa *Vista*, y a ella deberías mandar todas las salidas).

### Solución propuesta

Indicas el `dataType` en Ajax:

```
    url: '/billar/views/modules/torneo/procesoTorneo.php', 
    dataType: 'json',
```

Modificas las verificaciones en `success`:

```
        /*
        * Se ejecuta cuando termina la petición y esta ha sido
        * correcta
        * */
        console.log(data);
        if (data.error) {
            /* Aquí hacer lo que quieras cuando sea error */
         } else {
             /* Aquí recuperar data[0].id que ahora sí será un JSON */
         }
```

Aplicando esto debería funcionar. Si algo no queda claro, puedes decirlo mediante un comentario en esta respuesta.

### Sugerencia para el código PHP

No tienes necesidad de usar `fetchAll()` para este caso, este método te crea un array de array, por eso luego tendrías que hacer la lectura así: `data[0].id`. Para filas únicas puedes usar `fetch` simplemente:

```
$array=$stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Así el dato no será un array de array y podrás hacer la lectura en JS de este modo: `data.id`, sin tener que referirte al índice `0`.

Comment: Gracias amigo.. No me habia dado cuenta que faltaba el atributo dataType.